# Problem implementing virtual method in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Hey I was trying to multiple inherit a pure virtual function using MVS2010 Compiler. So I can run a draw for all renderable objects.

So here is the diagram

in ASCII

```
|Renderable            | |Entity             |
|virtual bool draw()=0;| | functions in here |

    is - a              is - a


                Shape
```

So it seems it wont let me inherit the pure virtual function? and implement the virtual function. Here is my code.

```
// Renderable.h
#ifndef H_RENDERABLE_
#define H_RENDERABLE_
class Renderable
{
 public:
    virtual bool Draw() = 0;
};
#endif


 //Shapes.h
 #ifndef H_SHAPES_
 #define H_SHAPES_
 #include "Renderable.h"
 #include "Entity.h"
 class Shapes : public Entity, public Renderable
 {
 public:
     Shapes();
     ~Shapes();

 };


 #endif

 //shapes.cpp
 #include "Shapes.h"


 Shapes::Shapes()
 {
 }


 Shapes::~Shapes()
 {
 }


 virtual void Shapes::Draw()
 {
 }
```

I have tried multiple things and it doesn't work also google searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare the draw function again in your Shapes class. Then make sure it has the same signature as the one declared in the Renderable class.

```
//Shapes.h
 #ifndef H_SHAPES_
 #define H_SHAPES_
 #include "Renderable.h"
 #include "Entity.h"
 class Shapes : public Entity, public Renderable
 {
 public:
     Shapes();
     ~Shapes();

     virtual bool Draw();

 };


 #endif

 //shapes.cpp

bool Shapes::Draw()
{
}
```

Comment: I think you mean  //shapes.cpp

bool Shapes::Draw()
{
}
instead of this
 //shapes.cpp

virtual bool Shapes::Draw()
{
}

Comment: It works now but why do I have to declare it, this seems a bit silly it should have a reference from the class it inherited from.

Comment: @WinterGreen but you declared the method Draw as pure virtual by specifying the =0 at the end, this mean that you force any inheriting class to define the method.

Comment: Oops! virtual keyword should not be use in method definition. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Your return types are not matching. The `Renderable::Draw` returns `bool`, and you `Shapes::Draw` returns `void`. The entire function signature (including the return types) must match, otherwise the function in the derived class simply hides the function in the base class.

Comment: Actually the return type does not need to be an exact match, rules are relaxed for covariant types.

Comment: @WinterGreen: Could you please post a complete, executable example that demonstrates what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare Draw in Shapes:

```
class Shapes : public Entity, public Renderable
{
  public:
    Shapes();
    ~Shapes();
    virtual void Draw(); 
};
```

Just defining it later is not enough.

Comment: Thanks this worked but
The since Renderable is virtual void Draw()=0; I just have to redefine it in the class.